# Assigning a sequential number to each duplicated string in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, counting, countif

I'm looking to assign a different value to rows that are duplicated in Google Sheets.  Below is an example of my current sheet that is pulled from a query.

```
School   Comp #  Name
School 1    3   Student A
School 1    4   Student B
School 2   10   Student C
School 3   15   Student D
School 3   20   Student E
School 4   25   Student F
```

Desired Outcome

```
Athlete #   School  Comp #  Name
Athlete 1   School 1    1   Student A
Athlete 2   School 1    2   Student B
Athlete 1   School 2    3   Student C
Athlete 1   School 3    4   Student D
Athlete 1   School 4    5   Student E
Athlete 1   School 5    6   Student F
```

Since schools may be sending 1 or 2 Athletes, I'm trying to automatically assign students to heats/lanes based on if they are the first or second athlete the school has registered.

Here is copy of the example sheet I'm working with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X9XVCI0pXIoTmG6rD61wvQXvyhFUlbIEzQztscSh33o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A="",,"Athlete "&COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, ROW(A:A), "<="&ROW(A:A))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem  to generate the Athlete # (1 or 2) beside the schools as necessary - it's assigning School 1 2xAthlete 1 and assigning the first entry for School 3 as Athlete 2 rather than Athlete 1 on the live spreadsheet I'm using

Comment: can you share a copy of your live sheet?

Comment: It has personal data so I can't - but I did borrow the countif from your suggestion and just removed the "Athlete" part, which is really irrelevant anyway.  I used the formula =if(isblank (I3),"",countif($I$3:I3,I3)) which worked perfectly to label the athletes as a 1 or 2 for each school.  Thanks for putting me on the right track